# Restructure Database using Oracle (SQL-Developer)

Tags: oracle11g, normalization, oracle-sqldeveloper

this might be a simple question, but I'll ask anyway :)

Lets say I got a table in a database (oracle) which is currently stored in the first normal form.

Now I would like to convert this table into the third normal form. But I don't exactly know how. OK, I know how to put the table into third NF on paper, no problem but how do I do it technically?

I'll just give an example:

My tabe has the following attributes:
InvoiceNr. | Date | StaffNr. | Name | Lastname | Street | Zip | City

Now I would like to put it in the following format:

---

Table Invoice: 
InvoiceNr. (PK) | Date | StaffNr.

Table Staff:
StaffNr. (PK) | Name | Lastname | Street | Zip

Table Zip:
Zip (PK) | City

---

Thank you very much in advance ;)
Thomas

Comment: Hello Mat, i updated my question with an example :)

Comment: well I dont exactly know HOW to put my table in my needed form. Does it work over commands or is there some kind of designer? :/

Comment: I just dont know which steps to take to let this happen in my physical database :(.

Comment: Yes I know that -.-. But what if this table already has a few thousand entries ... then I would have to re-enter all datasets?

Comment: you would need to create the new target tables and write some scripts to select from the source table and insert into the new tables